# C# JsonSerializer.Deserialize fails if property has null value despite JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, .net-6.0, system.text.json

From an external webservice i receive either

```js
// jsonWithConfig 
// property config is an object {}
{"config":{"c1":"All","c2":"is peachy"},"message":"We found a config object"} 

// jsonNoConfig
// property config is string with the value null
{"config":"null","message":"Config is null"}
```

I want to deserialize the json into these types

```cs
public class WebResponse
{     
   [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]   
   public Config Config { get; set; }  
   public string Message { get; set; } 

   // i also tried dynamic but 
   //    a) this is not what i want
   //    b) it resulted in RuntimeBinderException
   // public dynamic Config { get; set; } 
}

public class Config
{
    public string C1 { get; set; }
    public string C2 { get; set; }
}
```

#### What have i tried?

From [How to ignore properties with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties) i started with [JsonSerializer.Deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0) from `System.Text.Json`

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions{
     DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
     PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};
    
string jsonWithConfig = 
       {"config":{"c1":"All","c2":"is peachy"},"message":"We found a Config"}   
WebResponse webResponseWithConfig = 
            JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WebResponse>(jsonWithConfig, options);
```

This works for `jsonWithConfig` which is no surprise since the json can be deserilized to the  type `WebResponse`.

#### What is the error?

I hoped that using [JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.defaultignorecondition?view=net-7.0) would work for `jsonNoConfig = {"config":"null","message":"Config is null"}`.
But deserialization of `jsonNoConfig` fails with `DeserializeUnableToConvertValue`

```cs
string jsonNoConfig = 
       {"config":"null","message":"Config is null"} 
WebResponse webResponseNoConfig = 
            JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WebResponse>(jsonNoConfig, options);
```

#### Questions

- How can i deserialize `jsonNoConfig`?
- What must i do?

#### Update

[MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19858830/) pointed out that `config` should have the value `null` and not `"null"`. After changing this the code above works as expected.

But is there a way to handle null with quotation marks like `{"config":"null", ...}` as well?

#### Full stack trace

The stack trace inside [linqpad](/questions/tagged/linqpad) shows this

> at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type
> propertyType)
>
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader&
> reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack&
> state, T& value)
>
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader&
> reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack&
> state, T& value)
>
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.ReadJsonAndSetMember(Object
> obj, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
>
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader&
> reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack&
> state, T& value)
>
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader&
> reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack&
> state, T& value)
>
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader&
> reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
>
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
>
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1
> json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
>
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json,
> JsonSerializerOptions options)    at UserQuery.Main(), line 13

### LINQPad program

This [linqpad](/questions/tagged/linqpad)-program has all the code needed

```cs
// Linqpad program
void Main()
{       
string jsonWithConfig = "{\"config\":{\"c1\":\"All\",\"c2\":\"is peachy\"},\"message\":\"We found a Config\"}";
string jsonNoConfig   = "{\"config\":\"null\",\"Message\":\"Config is null\"}";
    
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions{
        DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};
        
WebResponse webResponseWithConfig = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WebResponse>(jsonWithConfig, options);
webResponseWithConfig.Dump();
WebResponse webResponseNoConfig = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WebResponse>(jsonNoConfig, options);   
    webResponseNoConfig.Dump();
}

// custom types
public class WebResponse
{     
   [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]   
   public Config Config { get; set; }     
   public string Message { get; set; }      
}

public class Config
{
    public string C1 { get; set; }
    public string C2 { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Linqpad demo]

Comment: Note that the config property in `{"config":"null","message":"Config is null"}` does **not** have null value. It has a **string** value composed of the characters `n`,`u`,`l`,`l` (an actual null value would not be in quotation marks). And since a string value is not convertible to an instance of type _Config_ you get an error...

Comment: This already helped. If i remove the quotes and change `"null"` to  `null` the conversion seems to work.

Comment: See update above - is there a way to handle `"null"` as well?

Comment: I don't know. Neither System.Text.Json nor Newtonsoft.Json support the `"null"` string as a null value. Depending on the complexity of the json you have to deserialize and the amount of different places a `"null"` string representing a null value might appear in the json, possible solutions could range from a rather hackish yet simple string replacement in the json string before feeding it to the deserializer to writing JsonConverter(s) for the affected properties/types.

Comment: If writing and testing the respective JsonConverters sounds like too much or too complicated work, or if there are simply too many types/properties to cover and too many places in the json where such a `"null"` might appear, there is always contacting the admins of the web service and bitching and begging like your life depends on it as last resort (not sure if that is a feasible option for your situation, though)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74856371/c-sharp-jsonserializer-deserialize-fails-if-property-has-null-value-despite-json#comment132106352_74856371) by [MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19858830/myskullcaveisadarkplace), your problem is that the JSON value `"null"`

```
"config":"null"
```

Is **not null**.  It is a non-null string value containing the characters `null`.  A null value looks like:

```
"config":null // Notice there are no quotes around the text
```

For confirmation, see the [original JSON proposal](https://json.org/).

If you cannot fix the JSON to represent null values properly, you will need to write a [custom JsonConverter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to) that checks for a `"null"` text value and returns `null` if present.  If not present, the converter should proceed with default deserialization.

The question *[How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65430420/3744182)* has [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430421/3744182) which provides a `DefaultConverterFactory<T>`. Grab it and subclass it as follows:

NullTextValueForNullObjectConverter

```cs
public sealed class NullTextValueForNullObjectConverter<T> :
 DefaultConverterFactory<T> where T : class
{
   const string NullValue = "null";
        
   protected override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, 
                 JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions) 
   {
      if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
      {
        var s = reader.GetString();
        // Or use StringComparison.Ordinal if you are sure the 
        // text "null" will always be lowercase
        if (string.Equals(s, NullValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
                    return null;
      }
      return (T)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions);
    }
}
```

DefaultConverterFactory

```cs
public abstract class DefaultConverterFactory<T> : JsonConverterFactory
{
    class DefaultConverter : JsonConverter<T>
    {
       readonly JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions;
       readonly DefaultConverterFactory<T> factory;

       public DefaultConverter(JsonSerializerOptions options, DefaultConverterFactory<T> factory)
       {
           this.factory = factory;
           this.modifiedOptions = options.CopyAndRemoveConverter(factory.GetType());
       }

       public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => factory.Write(writer, value, modifiedOptions);

       public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
            => factory.Read(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions);
    }

    protected virtual T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions)
            => (T)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions);

    protected virtual void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions) 
            => JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, modifiedOptions);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) 
            => typeof(T) == typeToConvert;

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
            => new DefaultConverter(options, this);
}
```

JsonSerializerExtensions

```cs
public static class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
    public static JsonSerializerOptions CopyAndRemoveConverter(this JsonSerializerOptions options, Type converterType)
    {
        var copy = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
        for (var i = copy.Converters.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (copy.Converters[i].GetType() == converterType)
                copy.Converters.RemoveAt(i);
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Then either add the converter to `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters` as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new NullTextValueForNullObjectConverter<Config>() },
    // Other options as required
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};
var webResponseWithConfig = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WebResponse>(jsonWithConfig, options);
```

Or apply to the `Config` property directly as follows:

```
[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]   
[JsonConverter(typeof(NullTextValueForNullObjectConverter<Config>))]
public Config Config { get; set; }
```

Note that there does not appear to be a way currently to generate a default serialization of you apply the converter directly to the `Config` type.  As such, I don't recommend doing it.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5mbdJ7).

Comment: This works great. For anyone who would like to test it and play around with it i copied the [code as linqpad program](https://gist.github.com/surfmuggle/e04d4699a3c6c305f4af721d3db0e73d)

Comment: Could it be that the re-serialization omits the `Config`-object? I changed line 105 to this `string webResponse2Json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(webResponseWithConfig , options);` and line 107 to this `Console.WriteLine("webResponse2Json" + webResponse2Json);`. For `jsonWithConfig` i expected that the config property has this object `{"c1":"All","c2":"is peachy"}` but actual got an empty object for the config property `{"Config":{}, ...}`

Comment: @surfmuggle - sorry, my mistake.  I forgot to pass `modifiedOptions` to `(T)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions);`.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot fix the JSON source then in this particular case i would recommend to replace `"null"` with `null` using a c# string replace function

```cs
json = json.Replace("\"null\"","null");
```

Comment: [Be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) is quite easy if you try. This comment refers to the [first version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74857354/revisions)